# 2D Delaunay, Divide and Conquer - Rare bug

Tags: c++, delaunay

I have been working on a two dimensional Divide and Conquer algorithm written in c++, a language I am rather new to. I used this [page](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/%7Esamuelp/del_project.html) to base my algorithm on. The Y-axis is inverted in my example images.

I create a grid with a chosen width and height. The program then selects a random coordinate within each cell, these are the points for the Delaunay Triangulation.

The algorithm works as follows

- Sort the coordinates in ascending order on the x-axis (similar x values; sort on y)
- Divide into subgroups, until each group contains no more than 3 coordinates. Connect each coordinate with a line (I call them 'Edges'). This is in a binary tree structure. The Leaves contain a vector of these edges.
- Recursively merge the leaves upwards

  - **#** Select the starting edge: select the coordinates, **L** and **R**, with the lowest y value from the left and right subgroup. If the edge **L-R** does not intersect with any edges of either group: select that edge. Else, select the next coordinate. (If the **L-R** edge intersects with an edge from the left subgroup select the next left coordinate. Ditto with the right group)
  - Based on the starting edge ('base' in my code) select the next candidate from both groups, **left_C** and **right_C** (the following is the left subgroup selection process, the right subgroup is the same but only mirrored):

    - Select the neighboring coordinates: all coordinates that have a direct connection to the base edge
    - Sort the neighbors by increasing clockwise angles.
    - **@** The candidate selection process: Select first (i = 0) coordinate as the candidate **C**, the second (i + 1) as the next candidate **nC**.

      1. Check if the angle between the **L-R** and **C** is bigger than 180° or pi. If so: no candidate is selected, else move on to the next condition.
      2. **&** Check if, the **nC** is within the circumcircle defined by triangle **L-R-C** (distance between circumcircle center and **nC** < radius circumcircle). delete the edge defined by **L-C**. **nC** becomes the new candidate **C**, the candidate with the next highest angle becomes **nC**, repeat check.
      3. return candidate at the position i
  - If neither left nor right groups return a candidate, then the merge is complete.
  - Else if only one group returns a candidate, obviously that is the to-be-used candidate
  - Else both subgroups return a candidate, then select the candidate where the circumcircle defined by it and the base edge does not contain the other.
  - A triangle is created using the selected candidate and the base edge: an edge is created between the candidate and base-coordinate from the other subgroup ( eg. candidate of the left-subgroup: **R-left_C** ). This becomes the base edge for the next iteration.
  - iterate until the merge is complete (neither subgroup offers a candidate)

And so the tree is merged recursively.

So TL;DR.

The issue that I am having is two steps of the D&C algorithm coming into conflict. the two are the selection of the starting base edge (see step **#**) and the selection of the candidate coordinates (see step **@** and **&**)

The bug (read: feature) occurs with this orientation of the subgroups:

Animated Gif
[image: Animated Gif]

It skips one of the coordinates of the right group in the first merger. This is because the algorithm specifies that you take the lowest y values of both groups that do not intersect with any other edges as the base edge. Then all the right group candidates, which *are attached to the base edge*, are selected with their counter-clockwise angle, the left with the clockwise angles. This skips one coordinate. leading to the following result.

I have no idea how to solve this.

Here is my code:

triangulate():

```
Node* Branch::triangulate() {
    if (l != nullptr && r == nullptr) {
        return l;
    }
    else {
        // recursive merge
        Node* left = l->triangulate();
        Node* right = r->triangulate();


        vector<Edge> left_edges = left->getEdges();
        vector<Edge> right_edges = right->getEdges();

        Edge base = selectBase(left_edges, right_edges);

        bool merge = true;
        vector<Edge> mergedEdges;
        vector<Edge> newEdges;
        newEdges.push_back(base);

        while (merge) {
            Coordinate left_candidate = selectCandidateFromSubgroup(left_edges, base, true);
            Coordinate right_candidate = selectCandidateFromSubgroup(right_edges, base, false);

            Coordinate null(DBL_MIN, DBL_MIN);
            if (left_candidate == null && right_candidate == null) {
                merge = false;
            }
            else {
                Edge new_base;
                if (right_candidate == null) {
                    new_base = Edge(left_candidate, *base.p2());
                }
                else if (left_candidate == null) {
                    new_base = Edge(*base.p1(), right_candidate);

                }
                else {
                    double left_a, left_b, left_c,
                        base_a, base_b, base_c;
                    functionFromEdge(base, base_a, base_b, base_c);

                    Edge left_edge(left_candidate, *base.p2());
                    

                    functionFromEdge(left_edge, left_a, left_b, left_c);
                    
                    perpendicularBisector(base, base_a, base_b, base_c);
                    perpendicularBisector(left_edge, left_a, left_b, left_c);

                    Coordinate left_circumcircle_center = intersection(left_a, left_b, left_c,
                                                    base_a, base_b, base_c);

                    new_base = (Coordinate::distance(left_circumcircle_center, left_candidate)
                                            < Coordinate::distance(left_circumcircle_center, right_candidate))
                                                ? left_edge : Edge(*base.p1(), right_candidate);
                }

                newEdges.push_back(new_base);
                base = new_base;
            }
        }

        mergedEdges.reserve(newEdges.size() + left_edges.size() + right_edges.size());
        for (Edge e : left_edges) {
            mergedEdges.push_back(e);
        }
        for (Edge e : right_edges) {
            mergedEdges.push_back(e);
        }
        for (Edge e : newEdges) {
            mergedEdges.push_back(e);
        }
        return new Leaf(mergedEdges,i);

    }
}
```

selectBase():

```
    vector<Coordinate> left_points = extractCoordinates(left);
    vector<Coordinate> right_points = extractCoordinates(right);
    Edge* out = nullptr;
    bool found = false;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (!found) {
        Coordinate l = left_points.at(i), r = right_points.at(j);
        Edge base(l, r);
        out = &base;
        for (Edge e : left) {
            if (out!= nullptr && e.intersects(base)) {
                //cout << e << " intersects with " << *out << " i++" << endl;
                i++;
                out = nullptr;
            }
            if (out != nullptr && left_points.size() ==2 && (*e.p1() == *base.p1() || *e.p2() == *base.p1())) {
                Coordinate other = (*e.p1() == *base.p1()) ? *e.p2() : *e.p1();

                if (Angle::calcClockAngle(l, r, other, true).rad() > M_PI) { 
                    out = nullptr; i++; 
                }
            }
        }
        for (Edge e : right) {
            if (out != nullptr && e.intersects(base)) {
                //cout << e << " intersects with " << *out << " j++" << endl;
                j++;
                out = nullptr;
            }
            if (out != nullptr && right_points.size() == 2 && (*e.p1() == *base.p2() || *e.p2() == *base.p2())) {
                Coordinate other = (*e.p1() == *base.p2()) ? *e.p2() : *e.p1();
                if (Angle::calcClockAngle(r, l, other, false).rad() > M_PI) {
                    out = nullptr; j++;
                }
            }
        }                                    
        if (out != nullptr) found = true;
    }
    return Edge(left_points.at(i), right_points.at(j));
}
```

In the above function I tried to make a check that checks if there is a skipped point, by checking in subgroups of size 2 if there is an angle larger than pi.

It worked for smaller groups. But the issue still occurs.

selectCandidateFromSubgroup:

```
Coordinate selectCandidateFromSubgroup(vector<Edge>& es, Edge& base, bool left) {
// select neighboring edges from base
    Coordinate* shared_point = (left)? base.p1() : base.p2();
    Coordinate* other_point = (left)? base.p2() : base.p1();
    
    vector<Coordinate> candidates;
    for (Edge e : es) {
        if (*shared_point == *e.p2() || *shared_point == *e.p1()) {
            Coordinate c = (*shared_point  == *e.p2()) ? *e.p1() : *e.p2();
            candidates.push_back(c);
        }
    }

    if (candidates.size() != 0) {

        algorithm::quicksort(candidates, 0, candidates.size() -1,
            [&shared_point,&other_point,&left](Coordinate a, Coordinate b) {
                double angle = Angle::calcClockAngle(*shared_point, *other_point, a, left).getDegrees();
                double angle2 = Angle::calcClockAngle(*shared_point, *other_point, b, left).getDegrees();
                return (angle < angle2 || (angle == angle2 && a.y() < b.y()));
            });


        double base_a, base_b, base_c;
        functionFromEdge(base, base_a, base_b, base_c);
        perpendicularBisector(base, base_a, base_b, base_c);



        Coordinate* candidate=nullptr;
        Coordinate* next_candidate = nullptr;

        int i = 0;
        bool checking_candidates = true;
        while (checking_candidates) {
            candidate = &candidates.at(i);
            double angle = Angle::calcClockAngle(*shared_point,
                                                    *other_point,
                                                    *candidate,
                                                    left).rad();
            if (angle < M_PI) {
                Edge candidate_edge;
                int cei = 0;
                int j = 0;

                for (Edge e : es) {
                    
                    if ((*e.p1() == *shared_point && *e.p2() == *candidate) || (*e.p2() == *shared_point && *e.p1() == *candidate)) {
                        candidate_edge = e;
                        cei = j;
                        break;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                if (i + 1 == candidates.size()) return *candidate;
                next_candidate= &candidates.at(i+1);
                double candidate_edge_a, candidate_edge_b, candidate_edge_c;
                functionFromEdge(candidate_edge, candidate_edge_a,
                                    candidate_edge_b, candidate_edge_c);
                perpendicularBisector(candidate_edge, candidate_edge_a,
                                        candidate_edge_b, candidate_edge_c);

                Coordinate circumcicle_center = intersection(base_a, base_b, base_c,
                    candidate_edge_a, candidate_edge_b, candidate_edge_c);

                double radius = Coordinate::distance(circumcicle_center, *shared_point);
                double distance_center_nCandidate = Coordinate::distance(circumcicle_center, *next_candidate);

                if (radius < distance_center_nCandidate) {
                    return *candidate;
                }
                else {
                    i++;
                    es.erase(es.begin() + cei);
                }
            }
            else {
                return Coordinate(DBL_MIN, DBL_MIN);
            }

        }
    }

    return Coordinate(DBL_MIN, DBL_MIN);
}
```

*extractCoordinates(vector)* extracts and sorts all coordiates on the y axis ascendingly.

*functionFromEdge(Edge,double a,double b,double c)* takes an edge and makes a functional representation of the lines like 'ax+by=c', which is used by

*perpendicularBisector(Edge, double a, double b, double c)* converts the a, b, and c values to represent the function of the perpendicular bisector of the Edge so that the algorithm can calulate the

*intersection(double a1, double b1, double c1, double a2, double b2, double c2)* of two functions.

the calcClockAngle(Coordinate a, Coordinate b, Coordinate c, bool clockwise) calulates the angle in a bewteen the vectors |AB| and |AC|, depending on the clockwise boolean, it calculates the cloclwise or counter clockwise angle.

If I forgot something please let me know.

Sorry for the long question. but I am seriously at a loss here.

I get results like this:

[image: 25x25 example]